# How to read Release Notes inside VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have restarted my VS Code today and it got updated. When it was opened again, I got a tab with Release Notes and a few minutes later decided to open my project to see the changes in action.

However, when I did open the project, the **Release Notes** tab closed and now **I can't find a way to access it specifically in VS Code**.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: There is a "Release Notes" option in the Help menu which also brings up the latest release notes in a tab.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just open the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Windows/Linux, <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on macOs), type *Show Release Notes*, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The release notes will be displayed on the same tab.

Answer (score 4):

It is also available from the **Help** menu > **Release Notes**.

[image: screenshot of Help menu + Release Notes sub-menu item]

It opens the same tab showing your VS Code's version's release notes:

[image: screenshot of tab for release notes]