# How can I display the what's new window again in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I updated my VSCode and upon restart it showed me what looks to be a what's new page.  I skimmed and then closed it. After a bit I realized that I wanted to reread something there again.  I tried to use <kbd>Alt-Left</kbd> to go back, but that window isn't in the go back/forth entries.  I've tried to look to find any command that would redisplay it again, to no avail.

How do I bring back that tab of information?

Comment: Are you talking about the release notes for a new vs code version? Or the "what's new" for a specific extension? Or the welcome/tour page for new users?

Comment: @GinoMempin, I'm guessing the release notes.  It's the first thing that comes up when you allow VSCode to do a self upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: Then it's a duplicate: [How to read Release Notes inside VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50268028/2745495)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can open them from the main menu under `Help` -> `Release Notes` or by running the `Code: Show Release Notes` command.